# How convert Object String to Data Class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, data-class

I want to convert below .tostring to data class how to convert?

```
InstrumentResponse(AGM=false, AllOrNone=true, Bonus=true, Dividend=true, EGM=false, AuctionDetailInfo=AuctionDetailInfo(AuctionNumber=0, AuctionStatus=0, InitiatorType=0)
```

What I am trying to do to pass data class though bundle from one fragment to another but doing with `bundle.putString` how to convert this again to a data class ?

Is there a better way to achieve ?  or how to convert `dataClass.toString` to Data class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `@Parcelize`.

Add

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

to you `build.gradle`.

Then add the annotation to you class

```
@Parcelize
data class InstrumentResponse(...)
```

Then put the value directly into the `Bundle`

```
bundle.putParcelable(key, instrumentReponse)
```

To retrieve the value, call

```
val instrumentReponse = bundle.getParcelable<InstrumentResponse>(key)
```

Comment: What if you have to value type 'Any'  and 'list or another data class'

Comment: `Any` won't work. Lists and other data classes will work as long as they are `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

Comment: that means I have to specify  return type

Comment: but sometimes I received  String or Int . how to handle such condition

Answer (score 0):

To pass data class between activities, **don't use toString**. Instead, use `putParcelable`. A parcelable is a custom serialization format for Android. See the official documentation (with examples) [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html).

---

If you don't want to dig into `Parcelable` implementation details, you can use the kotlin [*experimental features*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable).

> Starting from Kotlin 1.1.4, Android Extensions plugin provides `Parcelable` implementation generator as an experimental feature.

In short, add

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

to your `build.gradle`, then use the `@Parcelize` annotation in your data class and make it inherit from `Parcelable`:

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class InstrumentResponse(...): Parcelable
```